# Book about a boy and a finger monkey

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel

I had borrowed a book about a boy and a finger monkey.

The boy had got the finger monkey from a create-anything box or something like that and found out a dispute over time travel machine which led to "accidents" and murder attempts.
The scientist behind the create-anything box and his friend were the 2 scientist part of the dispute where the other's wife caused the "accidents" for keeping the time machine all to herself and her husband.
The rest of the story was how the boy and the finger monkey found out about it and solved it.

Comment: What is a "finger monkey"?

Comment: According to Wikipedia ["finger monkey" = _pygmy marmoset_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_monkey) = the smallest primate in the world (unless, in this context, it's something completely different ...).

Answer (score 6):

I haven't read it, but on the grounds that there can't be that many science fiction books about finger monkeys I'm going to suggest [The Imagination Box](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25162386-the-imagination-box) by Martyn Ford:

[image: The Imagination Box]

> There is a box. Anything you imagine will appear inside. You have one go, one chance to create anything you want. What would you pick?" That's exactly the question ten-year-old Timothy Hart gets to answer after discovering The Imagination Box. The greatest toy on earth. The top-secret contraption transforms his life but when the box's inventor, Professor Eisenstone, goes missing, Tim knows he has to investigate. With the help of a talking finger monkey called Phil, he sets out to find the professor. In order to rescue his friend, he must face his darkest fears and discover the true potential of his own mind.

The Goodreads article does not mention time travel, but the eponymous box is a box that can create anything, and the boy Tim does use it to create a talking finger monkey (called Phil) to be a friend. So it matches the description in these respects. This is the first book in a  series so later books might have the time travel plot.

Comment: The third book in the series contains time travel; https://summerreadingchallenge.org.uk/book/15663686